# Уникальные числа при помощи php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Даже не знаю, как правильно задать вопрос. Суть такова. Пытался и пытаюсь написать функцию, которая бы считала, сколько уникальных чисел находится в определённом числе. Хочу, чтоб функция выводила, как в списке ниже:

- $nb = 0; // на выходе должно получится 0
- $nb = 1; // на выходе должно получится 1
- $nb = 2; // на выходе должно получится 2
- ...
- $nb = 13; // на выходе должно получится 13
- $nb = 14; // на выходе должно получится 0 0
- $nb = 15; // на выходе должно получится 0 1
- $nb = 16; // на выходе должно получится 0 2
- ...
- $nb = 27; // на выходе должно получится 0 13
- $nb = 28; // на выходе должно получится 1 0
- $nb = 29; // на выходе должно получится 1 1
- $nb = 30; // на выходе должно получится 1 2
- ...
- $nb = 196; // на выходе должно получится 0 0 0
- $nb = 197; // на выходе должно получится 0 0 1
- $nb = 198; // на выходе должно получится 0 0 2
- ...
- $nb = 392; // на выходе должно получится 1 0 0
- $nb = 393; // на выходе должно получится 1 0 1
- $nb = 393; // на выходе должно получится 1 0 2
- ...
- $nb = 2743; // на выходе должно получится 13 13 13
- $nb = 2744; // на выходе должно получится 0 0 0 0
- $nb = 2745; // на выходе должно получится 0 0 0 1
- $nb = 2746; // на выходе должно получится 0 0 0 2
- ...

А у меня получается какая-то логическая ошибка, что при вводе числа 392, выводится `1 14 -196`, а при 393 `1 14 -195` ну и т.д. И ещё при вводе более крупного и маленького числа в переменную `$nb` тоже выводится логическая ошибка. Вот например при вводе числа 15, мне выводится `-0 -12 -181`. Пытался всё это динамично сделать, но за 5 дней практически никуда не двинулся.

Вот сама функция:

```
// на это число делю
$count = 14;
// число
// минимальное возможное число при $count'е 14 может быть только 196
// максимальное возможное число при $count'е 14 может быть только 391
$nb = 391;
// предыдущая так сказать граница
$pr_nb = explode('.', log($numb, $count))[0];
$pr_nb = pow($count, $pr_nb);
// первый остаток
$balance1 = $nb - $pr_nb;
// второй остаток, предпоследнее число
$balance2 = explode('.', $balance1 / $count)[0];
$balance2a = explode('.', log($balance2, $count))[0];

// третий остаток, последнее число
$balance3 = $balance1 - (explode('.', $balance2 * $count)[0] * explode('.', log($balance1, $count))[0]);
// четвёртый остаток, это 3-я цифра с конца
$balance4 = explode('.', $balance1 / (pow($count, 2)))[0];

echo '<h1 style="color:red;">['.$balance4.'] ['.$balance2.'] ['.$balance3.']</h1>';
```

Принцип такой, если число в переменной `$nb` будет находится между значениями 14 во 2-й степени, то это число, будет записываться 3-мя числами (от `0 0 0` до `13 13 13`). Если в 3-й степени, то 4-мя (от `0 0 0 0` до `13 13 13 13`), если в 4-й степени, то 5-ю цифрами (от `0 0 0 0 0` до `13 13 13 13 13`) и т.д.

Знаю, что код просто ужас. Поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Ну то есть перевести число в 14-ричную систему счисления минус единица со старшего разряда...

Comment: @Akina да, что-то вроде того

Comment: Ну тогда какие сложности? есть штатная функция base_convert, которая переведёт в 14-ричку, есть и декремент первого байта строковой переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, вроде результат похож на правду, если устроят 14-ричные цифры:

```
$count = 14;
$nb = 2743;
$tmp = base_convert($nb, 10, $count);
$ch = $tmp[0];
$tmp[0] = --$ch;
echo $tmp;
```

Comment: Объясните мне, что-то я совсем не догоняю, выводит ddd так и должно выводить?

Comment: Угу. В 14-ричной (и более) системе счисления цифра d есть десятичная 13.

Comment: Понял. Думаю щас буду просто отдельно заменять буквы на нужные цифры. Спасибо большое!